# Twilio not dialing always

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

we are using Twilio agent-dialing to initiate the call between two users.

1. User A request a call to user B
2. We get the number from the WS, then create a call with Twilio
3. Twilio dials user A **SOMETIMES fails here**
4. When user A answers, then Twilio dials user B

This works fine most of the time, but some times the call is not even initiated. We get the call.getSid() as if the call was launched, but the phone never rings.

```
    if (!from.equals(to)) {
        Twilio.init(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_ACCOUNT_TOKEN);
        try {
            final String encodedNumber = URLEncoder.encode(to, "UTF-8");
            final String url = URL + "/connect/" + encodedNumber;

            final Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber(from), new PhoneNumber(TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER), new URI(url)).setTimeout(20).create();
            response.setMessage("Calling " + response.getItem().getDisplayName() + "'s " + params.getNumberType() + "...");

            LoggerUtil.out("Call done through Twilio: " + call.getSid() + " from: " + from + " to: " + to);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | URISyntaxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            response.setMessage("I cannot dial " + response.getItem().getDisplayName() + "'s " + params.getNumberType() + " now, please try again later.");
        }
    } else {
        response.setMessage("You cannot call yourself.");
    }
```

OUTPUT: Call done through Twilio: CAabf9ba78b3b94921b000cda2ae6d2b91 from: +521234567890 to: +520987654321

And, on Twilio console there are no errors on either. Also, we noticed that the $ decreases, which means we got charged (non-trial account), as the "call was made", but it was not.

Does anybody faced same issue? The same happens SOMETIMES, for the Agent side (bullet #4 on above steps): User A answers, but user B is never called (no dialing sound or anything at all on the user A phone, just void):

```
        final Dial dial = new Dial.Builder().number(number).build();
        final VoiceResponse voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build();
```

As said, this is happening sometimes, and most of the times for non-US phones (it also happens for US ones, but in small rates).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Twilio Call Logs to validate that we have successfully received and processed the incoming call(s). You can view the logs and search for your call record via either Console, or the REST API.

A record doesn't exist for the call: If you don't see a record for the call in question, then there is likely an issue elsewhere. Continue reading for additional troubleshooting.

A record does exist for the call: If you do see a record for the call in question, this indicates Twilio has successfully received the call, and the issue lies elsewhere. Continue troubleshooting with the following checklist:

Are you https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025446533-Troubleshooting-Twilio-Elastic-SIP-Trunking-and-SIP-Domain-Calls
Are you (or a caller) hearing the "An application error has occurred” error on your call?
Is an outbound call not connecting?
Does the call log show any Debug Events?
Is your TwiML URL or Application SID responding as intended?
Are you (or a caller) experiencing any audio quality issues?